# How can I use FOR JSON to build JSON in this format?

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016, for-json

I'd like to use `FOR JSON` to build a data payload for an HTTP Post call. My Source table can be recreated with this snippet:

```
drop table if exists #jsonData;
drop table if exists #jsonColumns;

select
    'carat' [column] 
into #jsonColumns
union
select 'cut' union
select 'color' union
select 'clarity' union
select 'depth' union
select 'table' union
select 'x' union
select 'y' union
select 'z'

select
    0.23 carat
    ,'Ideal' cut
    ,'E' color
    ,'SI2' clarity
    ,61.5 depth
    ,55.0 [table]
    ,3.95 x
    ,3.98 y
    ,2.43 z
into #jsonData
union
select 0.21,'Premium','E','SI1',59.8,61.0,3.89,3.84,2.31 union
select 0.29,'Premium','I','VS2',62.4,58.0,4.2,4.23,2.63 union
select 0.31,'Good','J','SI2',63.3,58.0,4.34,4.35,2.75
;
```

The data needs to be formatted as follows:

```
{
    "columns":["carat","cut","color","clarity","depth","table","x","y","z"],
    "data":[
        [0.23,"Ideal","E","SI2",61.5,55.0,3.95,3.98,2.43],
        [0.21,"Premium","E","SI1",59.8,61.0,3.89,3.84,2.31],
        [0.23,"Good","E","VS1",56.9,65.0,4.05,4.07,2.31],
        [0.29,"Premium","I","VS2",62.4,58.0,4.2,4.23,2.63],
        [0.31,"Good","J","SI2",63.3,58.0,4.34,4.35,2.75]
    ]
}
```

My attempts thus far is as follows:

```
select
    (select * from #jsonColumns for json path) as [columns],
    (select * from #jsonData for json path) as [data]
for json path, without_array_wrapper
```

However this returns arrays of *objects* rather than *values*, like so:

```
{
    "columns":[
        {"column":"carat"},
        {"column":"clarity"},
        {"column":"color"},
        {"column":"cut"},
        {"column":"depth"},
        {"column":"table"},
        {"column":"x"},
        {"column":"y"},
        {"column":"z"}
    ]...
}
```

How can I limit the arrays to only showing the values?

Comment: Please do show us your attempts, as if you're almost there, it's far easier for us to correct them.

Comment: Looking at the expected results, however, it doesn't look like particularly well formed JSON data.

Comment: @Larnu updated; I managed to fix one of the two issues. I make no comment on the validity of the format; it's mandated by the constraints of the intended recipient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, this seems like it's going to be easier with string aggregation rather than using the JSON functionality.

Because you're using using SQL Server 2016, you don't have access to `STRING_AGG` or `CONCAT_WS`, so the code is a lot longer. You have to make use of `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF` instead and insert all the separators manually (why there's so many `','` in the `CONCAT` expression). This results in the below:

```
DECLARE @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SELECT N'{' + @CRLF +
       N'    "columns":[' + STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[name],'"')
                                   FROM tempdb.sys.columns c
                                        JOIN tempdb.sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
                                   WHERE t.[name] LIKE N'#jsonData%' --Like isn't needed if not a temporary table. Use the literal name.
                                   ORDER BY c.column_id ASC
                                   FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,N'') + N'],' + @CRLF +
       N'    "data":[' + @CRLF +
       STUFF((SELECT N',' + @CRLF +
                     N'       ' + CONCAT('[',JD.carat,',',QUOTENAME(JD.cut,'"'),',',QUOTENAME(JD.color,'"'),',',QUOTENAME(JD.clarity,'"'),',',JD.depth,',',JD.[table],',',JD.x,',',JD.y,',',JD.z,']')
              FROM #jsonData JD
              ORDER BY JD.carat ASC
              FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,3,N'') + @CRLF +
      N'    ]' + @CRLF +
      N'}';
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=90b0e6ebf9c79ab933f25b2277676e2e)

Comment: thanks, lemme try this. You missed a comma which I can't insert because 6char minimum for edits;  `FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,N'') + N']' + @CRLF +` should be `FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,N'') + N'], ' + @CRLF +`